# Push navigation iPad issue

Tags: iphone, swift, ipad, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that uses a `UITabBarController` and has 4 children (navigation controllers).

iPad:
I am in the first tab (navigation controller) and I push a `UIViewController` from a cell. The view (x) that is now showing is under the top and bottom bars.

I then navigate to the second tab (navigation controller) and then again back to my first tab.

Now the view (same X) is displayed ok and not under the bars anymore.

If I test this on an iPhone the view is always rendered as it should (and not under the bars). All the navigation controller and all the viewControllers have `underTopBars` / `underBottomBars` and `adjustScrollViewInsets` deselected.

```
let releaseViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "qwerty") as? VCClass
releaseViewController?.navigationItem.title = datasource.asd?.name
releaseViewController?.datasource = datasource.asd
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(releaseViewController!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check these box in your storyboard for both controllers.

[image]

Let me know if it has worked.

Comment: Ahah no problem !